# Weblogic 10.3 ClassCast exception for OracleConnection

Tags: oracle, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to send the database Array by using the method below:

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = (OracleConnection) ((WLConnection)connection).getVendorConnection(); -- Exception in this LINE
ArrayDescriptor arrayDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "MY_ARRAY", oracleConnection);
String vals = {"1", "2"}
ARRAY ocbsArray = new ARRAY(arrayDesc, oracleConnection, vals);
```

Exception:

We are not having the WLConnection class in weblogic.jar in weblogic 10.3.

If I just send the typecasted oracleConnection object to the createDescriptor() method, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy439 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:155)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:123)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use com.bea.core.datasource module jar, in our weblogic modules directory.
This has the class WLConnection.